# NSMutableArrays and memory in loops

Tags: objective-c, macos, for-loop, memory, nsarray

Apologies first of all for the rather vague title but I'm not entirely sure how to categorise the question.

I'm using Xcode 8.1 on High Sierra and I've been banging my head against what really ought to be a simple piece of code.  I think I'm failing to grasp something key about Objective-C memory allocation.

So, first something I seem to have sorted.

I tried the following code:

```
fullDetails = [[NSArray alloc] init];
for( lineContent in fileByLine)
{
    fullDetails = [lineContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];
}
```

When I run this I get 27 entries in fileByLine and fullDetails correctly gets populated, line by line.  However, nothing goes into fullDetails, despite the fact that it has been initialised.  I worried that it is somehow nil until an initial value is inserted, so I also tried populating by index, with the index starting at zero.  Same effect.

However, the following code works fine:

```
for( lineContent in fileByLine)
{
    fullDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[lineContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
}
```

(I did say it ought to be really simple.)

So, I understand how to get the result I want but I really don't see why the first gobbet doesn't work.  I guess it's something about the scope of the variable inside and outside the for loop - but why?

I now come to the real problem (for me).  In the expanded gobbet:

```
NSString *newEntry = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *workingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( lineContent in fileByLine)
{
    fullDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[lineContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
    newEntry = [fullDetails objectAtIndex:1];
    [workingArray addObject:newEntry];
}
```

everything works fine (including newEntry) but I am unable to add the iterated newEntry items to the workingArray: I don't get an error; just 0 entries.

I've tried various mods to the addObject line.  In particular, I worried that it was simply overwriting a single NSString store (although, even then, I should have had one item).  So I tried:

```
NSString *newEntry = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *workingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( lineContent in fileByLine)
{
    fullDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[lineContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
    newEntry = [fullDetails objectAtIndex:1];
    [workingArray addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:newEntry]];
}
```

and

```
NSMutableArray *workingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( lineContent in fileByLine)
{
    fullDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[lineContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
    NSString *newEntry = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fullDetails objectAtIndex:1]];
    [workingArray addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:newEntry]];
}
```

and

```
NSMutableArray *workingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for( lineContent in fileByLine)
{
    fullDetails = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[lineContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"]];
    [workingArray addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithString:[fullDetails objectAtIndex:1]]];
}
```

So, please tell me what I'm missing.  I'm sure it's something pretty obvious but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Xcode (to version 9.4.1) and it now works fine.  So, it appears to have been a bug in the old version (although I'm loathe to cry, "bug!": it's too easy a solution).  Anyway, one answer that ought to have been obvious: make sure I'm using the latest version.